# Lack of sleep and gym working out

Tags: sleep, muscle-gain

I need help on this topic. 
I get up at 4am and come back home at 11pm which means im in bed at 12am and getting up at 4 am again ( and the cycle repeats) 
Im want to start working out at a local gym but im afraid that the lack of sleep time will affect anything ( gains, fatloss, etc). 
What can i do in order to max gains and fatloss? or shouldnt even start working outat a gym?

Comment: Although you didn't ask this, it seems to me that 4 hours of sleep a night, sustained, is extremely unhealthy.  There is apparently a small subgroup of people who can get by fine on about 5 hrs a night, but for most people 4 hours is dangerous--certainly in terms of driving a car, but also is likely to have long term consequences on one's heart, brain, and other systems.  Working out on top of this is going to add even more burden.  Is there any way you can change your life to get 7-8 hrs of sleep consistently??

Answer (score 5):

With your current lifestyle and the resulting sleeping pattern, your recovery is probably severely compromised. You will most likely not be able to work as hard as you should, will not recover as fast as you could and will feel the soreness much more than other people.

The good news is that working out can still be beneficial though. As a beginner you can do pretty much anything and get better, no matter how sub-optimal your program or recovery. Until these 'newb gains' taper off, you should be fine even with only a few hours of sleep. After that you can just continue and see how it goes. Too little sleep surely isn't the best way to make gains, but it's not the killer of all progress either. If you do it right (and smart), you can work out enough to keep making gains while still recovering okay-ish.

I also answered some similar questions already, so I'll just link you to those questions. Maybe you will find something helpful there:

- [The minimum program I would recommend if you have no time (or have bad recovery, as you will probably have)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16464/is-this-enough)
- [Advice on minimising exhaustion and maximizing recovery](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16295/how-to-compensate-for-extended-cardio-as-body-builder)

Comment: Thank you very much!!... the only thing is that i have been in this business for around 15 years, and always managed to work very well, matter of facts, until december i was around 13%BF, but doing sports i dislocated my elbow... so im coming back from an injury and have a different job position (in the pharma world) so it is a complex equation :( ...thank you, a lot!!!!